# Update TextView on UiThread from Async - Android

Tags: android, rest, okhttp

I am using OkHttp3 to do a GET API call, which works, however I would like to update a TextView (jsonTextView) in the UiThread with the result of the GET call.

I have tried 10 different ways but it does not work. Always tells me that can't resolve this or that therefore I ask that if you decide to help me, please take into account posting any dependencies on your answer such as import or declaration.

I left a line in my rest class: "CODE TO UPDATE jsonTextView IN UITHREAD". In your opinion what is the best way to achieve this?

Thank you so much in advance, I already lost hours on this.

This is my activity

```
package it.test.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

import android.os.*;

import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button fetchUpdateButton;
    TextView jsonTextView;
    EditText assetCode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fetchUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fetchUpdateButton);
        fetchUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(fetchAssetUpdateClick);

        jsonTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jsonTextView);
        assetCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.assetCode);

    }

    View.OnClickListener fetchAssetUpdateClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            REST r = new REST();

            try {

                r.getAssetUpdates(assetCode.getText().toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                jsonTextView.setText("API Fetch Failed");

            }

        }
    };
}
```

This is my REST class

```
package it.test.test;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.Headers;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;


/**
 * Created by fabio on 25/02/2017.
 */

public class REST  {

    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public void getAssetUpdates(String assetCode) throws Exception {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://10.0.0.3:8080/api/api/assets/getAsset?networkAssetCode=" + assetCode)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                try (final ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                    for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                        System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                    }

                    System.out.println(responseBody.string());

                    CODE TO UPDATE jsonTextView IN UITHREAD

                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update the other class UI from the REST class unless you put the callback into the method definition.

```
public void getAssetUpdates(String assetCode, Callback callback) {
    ... 
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
}
```

it's simply moving around some variables

Then, in the `onClick` define your callback so you can access your TextView in that Activity class ,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ... 
    r.getAssetUpdates(assetCode.getText().toString(), 
        new Callback() {
        @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try (final ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                ...

                // update UI in here
            } 
        }
    );
 }
```

And I do think Okhttp requires a usage of runOnUiThread.

[OkHTTP Update UI from enqueue callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418232/okhttp-update-ui-from-enqueue-callback)

---

Note that if you have JSON and REST, then Retrofit is going to be better than pure Okhttp.

Comment: This seems like the right answer. I think you should show the class and method which contains each change in order to provide context.

Comment: Can you please provide the entire code? I am a bit lost on using the callback parameter since inside the enqueue parenthesis should fit an entire method that contains my code.

Comment: What exactly is unclear? All I did was "extract" `new Callback()` into the parameter, and defined it instead in the Activity code

Comment: Can you update the entire answer? I am sorry I am new to Android. What you said now makes sense but I can't see through.

Comment: I don't know what more to add. I'm not going to re-write your entire question into a copyable answer. This solution is very generic, and anyone should be able to come here and see that I only "moved" the `new Callback()` code that you *already have* into the Activity's `onClick`

Comment: Thanks now I understood, however it is throwing exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed. Would you know why?

Comment: Figured out why the exception I was using the .string() 2 times. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to give an `Activity` to `REST` and call [`runOnUiThread()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)).

Comment: Holding onto an Activity reference? Why? ;P

Comment: @cricket_007 because I am unfamiliar with OkHttp.

Comment: It's almost identical to Volley

Answer (score 0):

Create own listener & pass the listener object from your activity..

And return the call back from Rest to your Activity

**Step 1: Create interface**

```
public interface MyListener
 {
 void restResult(String result);
 }
```

**Step 2:Implement this listener to your activity**

```
YourActivity implements MyListener
```

**Step 3:Pass the listener to Rest class**

```
Rest rest=new Rest(this);//this-- your listener object
```

**Step 4:Modify Rest Constructor**

```
Private MyListener myListener;
 Rest(MyListener myListener){
 this.myListener=myListener;
 }
```

//After your Rest completed pass the result

CODE TO UPDATE jsonTextView IN UITHREAD

```
myListener.restResult(responseBody.string());
```

**Step 5: In your Activity get your result**

Update the textview using

```
@override
restResult(String result){ 
 yourtextview.settext(result);
}
```

Comment: I tried your proposed solution, but it throws exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed

Comment: Thanks for giving this solution! I think it worked but I had to give the answer to the other reply. Thanks again!